# Copy test resources from one submodule to the others

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module maven project like this:

```
-project
+-sub-project1
+-sub-project2
```

For my JUnit tests, I create another `persistence.xml` file inside the `sub-project1/src/test/resources/META-INF`. This project is a dependency for the sub-project2, in this way, I was hopping that the tests of sub-project2 use the same test persistence.xml from sub-project1, but it not happen.

So, I was wondering why I can made maven automatically copy this file to the other submodules during the test phase... maybe it's better if I put this file in the `project/resources` folder, e.g., and then copy them...

I was hopping that someone already managed this to work somehow, and can help me or show how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed it to work like this:

I create a `project/assembly/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` file, and add this to my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-test-persistence-xml-resources</id>
            <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>src/</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/assembly/</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It works gracefullt.

Comment: Works like a charm.  I'm using it to copy my persistence.xml from my parent project's src/test/resources/META-INF directory into each of the sub-module directories.